# Perfect square : $ m+n+p-2\sqrt{mnp}=1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $m, n, p$ be positive integers such that $$ m+n+p-2\sqrt{mnp}=1$$

Prove that at least one of $m, n, p$ is a perfect square.

My attempt :

$ (m+n+p-1)^2=4mnp$

so $4mnp$ is a perfect square, i.e., $mnp$ is a perfect square.

Let $q$ be a prime such that $q\mid mnp$, so $q^2\mid mnp$.

Please suggest on how to proceed.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1240914_one_binary_form

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1052742_diophantine_equation_from_the_greek

Comment: @individ, Thank you for the useful links.

Comment: I am still confused.