# $m+n+p-1=2\sqrt{mnp}$ in positive integers

Tags: number-theory, vieta-jumping

If $m,n,p \in N$ and $m+n+p-1=2\sqrt{mnp}$, prove that at least one of 
$m,n,p$ is a perfect square.

There is a duplicate here: [Perfect square : $ m+n+p-2\sqrt{mnp}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390965/perfect-square-mnp-2-sqrtmnp-1), but I am very confused.

Now I have proven $\gcd(m,n,p)=1$

And I let $\gcd(m,n)=d_1$, $\gcd(m/d_1,p)=d_2$, and $\gcd(n/d_1,p/d_2)=d_3$

I have $d_1d_2m_2^{2}+d_1d_3n_2^{2}+d_3d_2p_2^{2}-1=2d_1d_2d_3m_2n_2p_2$, where $d_1d_2m_2^{2}=m$, $d_1d_3n_2^{2}=n$ and $d_3d_2p_2^{2}=p$

Then I don't know what to do.

Comment: Seems fairly difficult to do this properly. There are an infinite set of "fundamental" solutions, namely any $m=n$ with $p=1.$ Proving those are all is likely to be the hard part. After that, Vieta Jumping should finish the thing.

Comment: Meanwhile: where did you get the problem?

Comment: I got it from my AwesomeMath summer camp. Is this an Olympiad problem?

Comment: I dont see any limitation for $m=n$, since 4 is perfect square then p must also be a perfect square.

Comment: Thank you Will!

Comment: I recommend this book, by the people who started the Awesome Math program: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2060411.Quadratic_Diophantine_Equations  I have requested a copy from the library, so I am not sure yet whether they discuss this specific problem. Certainly Mordell's 1953 article on $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xyz = 1$ is one of their references. See Carl's answer for the relationship with your question

Answer (score 3):

I have parts of this, not enough. It is sometimes the case that problems are proposed for which the organizers do not genuinely possess a full proof.

Just so you know, it is quite difficult to find solutions with three distinct numbers. Meanwhile, the "new m" is the result of what is often called Vieta Jumping. Maybe I should put a little detail, as Carl may have finished the problem, but it depends on compatibility of  the "jumping" versions. The original equation squares to
$$ m^2 + n^2 + p^2 +2mn+2np+2pm - 4mnp -2m-2n-2p+1=0.   $$
Collecting this as a quadratic equation in $m$ alone, we get
$$ m^2 - (4np-2n-2p+2)m  + (n+2 + 2np + p^2 -2n -2p+1 ) = 0  $$
If there is one integer solution with this $m,$ there is another we can call $m',$ with $m+m' = (4np-2n-2p+2),$ finally the new $m$ value is
$$ m' =  (4np-2n-2p+2) - m $$ 
The jump is from the triple (solution ) $(m,n,p)$ to $(m',n,p)$

I should include the reason the this version of jumping preserves squares, so also preserves non-squares. Now, if $m$ is a square, the fact that $\sqrt {mnp}$ is rational means $np$ is also a square. Note that we have $2 \sqrt{mnp} = m+n+p-1$ and $4 \sqrt{mnp} = 2m+2n+2p-2.$

Consider
$$ \color{red}{Q = \left( \sqrt m - 2 \sqrt {np} \right)^2} \; . $$
$$  Q = m + 4np - 4 \sqrt{mnp} = m + 4np - (2m+2n+2p-2) \; , $$
$$  Q = 4np -2n-2p+2 - m \; . $$ This is the same as $m'$ in the jump. **So, when $m$ is a square**,
$$  \color{red}{m' = \left( \sqrt m - 2 \sqrt {np} \right)^2} \;  $$ 
**is also a square.**

```
m + n + p - 1 = 2 sqrt( m n p )

new m = 4 n p - 2 n - 2 p + 2 - m


(1,n,n) is a solution, maps to
( (2 n - 1)^2, n, n).

DISTINCT m > n > p :

50   9   2     new m:  2   9   2
243   25   3     new m:  3   25   3
289   50   2     new m:  9   50   2
676   49   4     new m:  4   49   4
1445   81   5     new m:  5   81   5
1682   50   9     new m:  2   50   9
1682   289   2     new m:  50   289   2
2401   243   3     new m:  25   243   3
2646   121   6     new m:  6   121   6
4375   169   7     new m:  7   169   7
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial characterization:

First, let $a=2m-1,b=2n-1,c=2p-1$. The equation reduces to

$$\frac{a+b+c+1}{2}=2\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{c+1}{2}\right)},$$

which after some manipulations becomes

$$2abc+1=a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

Writing in terms of $a$ we get

$$a^2-2abc+(b^2+c^2-1)=0.$$

We see that we can, via [Vieta Jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping), go from the solution $(a,b,c)$ to $(2bc-a,b,c)$. As such, if $a>bc$ (or, for that matter, $b>ca$ or $c>ab$), we can find a solution with smaller sum.

---

**Claim.** If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers $\geq 1$ where $a<bc,b<ca,c<ab$, then

$$2abc+1>a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

*Proof.* Assume the contrary. As $a^2-2abc+(b^2+c^2-1)\geq 0$, and $a$ cannot be greater than the larger root of this quadratic (as that would give $a>bc$), we must have

$$a\leq bc-\sqrt{(b^2-1)(c^2-1)}.$$

However, $a>b/c,c/b$. WLOG let $b\geq c$. Then

$$\frac{b}{c}< bc-\sqrt{(b^2-1)(c^2-1)}$$

$$\sqrt{(b^2-1)(c^2-1)} < bc-\frac{b}{c}$$

$$b^2c^2-b^2-c^2+1 < b^2c^2-2b^2+\frac{b^2}{c^2}$$

$$(b^2-c^2)\left(1-\frac{1}{c^2}\right) < 0.$$

However, $b\geq c$ and $c\geq 1$ imply together that both factors on the left are positive, a contradiction.

---

From this claim, we see that we can reduce any solution for which $a\neq bc,b\neq ca,c\neq ab$ to one with a smaller sum. As a result, every solution can be "jumped to" from a solution where, WLOG, $a=bc$. This reduces to $(b^2-1)(c^2-1)$, so either $b=1$ or $c=1$, which results in our solution set $(1,n,n)$ (and permutations, of course).

So, every solution can be "jumped to" from a solution of the form $(1,n,n)$.

Comment: If you are saying that every solution (m,n,p) in the original problem jumps down to a (1,w,w), using the Vieta description in my answer, then we are finished, because that process preserves squares and preserves nonsquares. If $p$ is a square, then also $mn$ is a square, and $$  p' = \left( \sqrt p - 2 \sqrt {mn} \right)^2 $$ If there were a solution $(m,n,p)$ with three nonsquares, this would imply the destination $(1,w,w)$ all nonsquares, a contradiction

Comment: I think we are in good shape. Your $a \mapsto bc-a,$ with values $a=2m-1$ and so on, multiplies out to $m \mapsto 4np-2n-2p+2-m$

Comment: Alright, I can see that you could write the square preservation of jumping in your own terms, it is just that the things being squares are $(a+1)/2$ or the others.

Comment: In comment four hours ago, should have written $a \mapsto 2bc - a.$ This matters in another way, you are considering the subset of solutions of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2 abc = 1$ where $a,b,c$ are always odd. Your Vieta jump evidently preserves parity.